# Generated Swagger file missing ApiOperation contents.Plugin is not parsing any content of the Api for unknown reason

Tags: swagger, swagger-maven-plugin

I want to use swagger and maven plugin to generate a documention in json-from from my restful application.The json file is created, but the data from the api with all descriptions of my code is missing.

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>de.baintern.infoplattform</groupId>
        <artifactId>infoplattform</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>infoplattform-services</artifactId>
    <name>infoplattform-services</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId> 3.2
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3-M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-alpha4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-alpha4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>       

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <apiSources>
                        <apiSource>
                            <locations>
                                <location>services.myServices</location>
                            </locations>
                            <schemes>
                                <scheme>http</scheme>
                                <scheme>https</scheme>
                            </schemes>
                            <host>localhost:7001</host>
                            <basePath>/info-services</basePath>
                            <info>
                                <title>Swagger documentation</title>
                                <version>v1</version>
                                <description>swagger documentation</description>
                                <termsOfService>
                                    http://localhost:7001/info-services/
                                </termsOfService>
                                <contact>
                                    <email>info.email@domaine.de</email>
                                    <name>Info-Box</name>
                                    <url>https:mydomain.de/</url>
                                </contact>
                                <license>
                                    <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
                                    <name>Apache 2.0</name>
                                </license>
                            </info>
                            <swaggerDirectory>generated/swagger-ui</swaggerDirectory>
                            <swaggerFileName>info-services</swaggerFileName>
                            <outputFormats>json</outputFormats>
                            <attachSwaggerArtifact>true</attachSwaggerArtifact>
                            <swaggerUIDocBasePath>http://localhost:7001/info-services/doc</swaggerUIDocBasePath>
                        </apiSource>
                    </apiSources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>      
    </build>    
</project>
```

This is my java code :

```
@Path("/themen")
@Api(value = "/themen", description = "Service-Methoden von Thema")
public class ThemaServices extends EjBFactoryAndUtils { 

@GET
    @Path("/findAllThemen")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Liefert alle Themen", notes = "Liest alle Themen aus der Datenbank ein nach bestimmten Parametern. Die Liste wird mit Parametern eingelesen.Alle diese Parameter sind optional.", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, httpMethod = "GET", responseContainer = "List")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found.", response = List.class) })
    public Response findAllThemen(
            @ApiParam(value = "Bestimmt ob die zugeordnete Elemente,wie Dokumente oder Themengruppen angezeigt werden.", required = false, name = "skipZuordnungen") @DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("skipZuordnungen") Boolean skipZuordnungen,
            @ApiParam(value = "Startposition der einzulesenden Daten", required = false, name = "startPosition") @QueryParam("startPosition") Integer startPosition,
            @ApiParam(value = "Maximale Anzahl der einzulesenden Daten", required = false, name = "maxResult") @QueryParam("maxResult") Integer maxResult) {

        .......     
    }
```

and the generated json file looks like that :

```
"/themen/findAllThemen" : {
      "get" : {
        "operationId" : "findAllThemen",
        "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "skipZuordnungen",
          "in" : "query",
          "required" : false,
          "type" : "boolean",
          "default" : true
        }, {
          "name" : "startPosition",
          "in" : "query",
          "required" : false,
          "type" : "integer",
          "format" : "int32"
        }, {
          "name" : "maxResult",
          "in" : "query",
          "required" : false,
          "type" : "integer",
          "format" : "int32"
        } ],
        "responses" : {
          "default" : {
            "description" : "successful operation"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

In this Json file, the information from @ApiOperation, @ApiResponses and @ApiParam is missing. The plugin is not parsing any content of the swagger-Api for unknown reason .
Please could someone help me to generate correctly this file with the missing content ?

Comment: Hi I am having similar issues with Swagger file generated from Jax-RS API, did you figure out a fix?